# Proof (More rigorous) for LeetCode: 11. Container With Most Water problem

Tags: solution-verification, computer-science, programming

I came across this problem yesterday and I was struggling understanding the solution. I'll give my version for the proof of correctness of the algorithm (leetcode lists such a problem as a *greedy* algorithm). I've seen few proofs around but none of them really satisfies me so I gave it a go between last night and this morning and I am sharing what the outcome is (hopefully correct).

Statement of the problem:

> You are given an integer array height of length n. There are n vertical lines drawn such that the two endpoints of the ith line are (i, 0) and (i, height[i]).
> Find two lines that together with the x-axis form a container, such that the container contains the most water.
> Return the maximum amount of water a container can store.
> Notice that you may not slant the container.

**The question is** whether or not what I derived is correct.

The solution been given, in code, is the following:

```
int maxArea(vector<int>& h) {
 int i=0,j=h.size()-1;
    int area=0;
    while(i<j){
        area=max(area,min(h[i],h[j])*(j-i));
        if(h[i]<h[j])
            i++;
        else
            j--;
    }
    return area;
}
```

Which can be rewritten in a recursive fashion as follows

```
int maxArea(vector<int>& h, int i, int j) {
        if(i >= j)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(h[i] < h[j])
        {
            return max(h[i]*(j-i),maxArea(h,i+1,j));
        }
        else
        {
            return max(h[j]*(j-i),maxArea(h,i,j-1));
        }
    }
    
int maxArea(vector<int>& h) {
        int n = h.size();
        return maxArea(h,0,n-1);
}
```

If we analyse the recursion defined by

$$
V(i,j) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & i \geq j \\
\max \left\{ V(i+1,j), h_i(j-i) \right\} & h_i < h_j \\
\max \left\{ V(i,j-1), h_j(j-i) \right\} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

And we show that for  $0 \leq i < j \leq n - 1$ and $a_{ij} = \min \left\{ h_i, h_j\right\}(j - i)$ we have

$$
V(i,j) = \max_{i \leq k < l \leq j} a_{kl}
$$

we're done.
I did this by induction on $j - i = n$, if $n = 1$ we have $i = 0, j = 1$ and
$$
V(0,1) = 
\begin{cases}
\max \left\{ V(1,1), h_0 \right\} & h_0 < h_1 \\
\max \left\{ V(0,0), h_1 \right\} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} =
\begin{cases}
\max \left\{ 0, h_0 \right\} & h_0 < h_1 \\
\max \left\{ 0, h_1 \right\} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} = \\
\begin{cases}
h_0 & h_0 < h_1 \\
h_1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} = \min \left\{ h_0, h_1 \right\} = a_{01}
$$

Suppose now that the statement holds if $j - i = n - 1$, we want to show it holds for $j - i = n$. I need to consider two cases $h_i < h_j$ and $h_i \geq h_j$ however since the proof is very similar I'll just prove the former.

The recursion in this case is simplified as

$$
V(i,j) = \max \left\{ V(i+1,j), h_i(j-i) \right\}
$$

Observe now since $j - i = n$ by hypothesis we have $j - (i + 1) = n - 1$ so the inductive hypothesis holds and we can rewrite

$$
V(i,j) = \max \left\{ \max_{i+1 \leq k < l \leq j} a_{kl}, h_i(j-i) \right\}
$$

Observe now that since for $i < l \leq j$ we have (just by definition of $\min$)
$$
\min \left\{h_i, h_l\right\} \leq h_i \Rightarrow \min \left\{h_i, h_l\right\}(l - i) \leq h_i(l - i) \Rightarrow \min \left\{h_i, h_l\right\}(l - i) \leq h_i(j - i)
$$

However since $h_i < h_j$ we specifically have $$\min \left\{h_i,h_j\right\}(j - i) = h_i(j-i)$$.

$$
\max_{i < l \leq j} \min \left\{h_i,h_l \right\}(l - i) = \min \left\{h_i,h_j \right\}  (j - i) \Rightarrow \max_{i < l \leq j} a_{il} = a_{ij}
$$.

I can therefore re-write $V(i,j)$ as

$$
V(i,j) = \max \left\{ \max_{i+1 \leq k < l \leq j} a_{kl}, h_i(j-i) \right\} =
\max \left\{ \max_{i+1 \leq k < l \leq j} a_{kl}, \max_{i < l \leq j} a_{il} \right\} = \max_{i \leq k < l \leq j} a_{kl}
$$

A final observation is the the branch in the if statement of my recursion, which means I don't have to solve all the subproblems. The solution of the final problem is given by calculating $V(0,n-1)$, which is a $O(n)$ time solution now, more specifically $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Link to the original question: https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/

Answer (score 1):

Consider 2 sequences:

- $a_0 = 0$
- $a_{k+1}$ is the smallest integer s.t. $a_{k+1} > a_{k}$ and $h[a_{k+1}] > h[a_j]$
- the last value of $a_{k}$ is the index of the first largest value of $h$.

$b$ is defined symmetrically:

- $b_0 = n-1$
- $b_{k+1}$ is the largest integer s.t. $b_{k+1} < b_{k}$ and $h[b_{k+1}] > h[b_k]$
- the last value of $b_{k}$ is the index of the last largest value of $h$.

[image: Picture of a,b sequences]

Note that $k \mapsto h[a_{k}]$ is strictly increasing, so is $k \mapsto h[b_{k}]$.

Any bucket whose left edge isn't in $a$ can be made larger by moving the left edge left.

Any bucket whose right edge isn't in $b$ can be made larger by moving the right edge right.

So only buckets whose left edge is in $a$ and whose right edge is in $b$ are worth consideration.

If the $h[a_s]$-edge is shorter than the $h[b_t]$ edge, then the area is just $h[a_s] \times (b_t - a_s)$.  So you want to compare it with the furthest right $b$-edge s.t. $h[a_s] \le h[b_t]$, which is easy because both sequences are strictly increasing.

When $h[b_t]$ is the shorter edge the reasoning is symmetric.

The fact that the algorithm also compares non $a$-$b$ edges is just vacuous, they'll never proc the `area=max(area,...)` line.

Comment: You're not answering if my derivation is correct or not.