# Proving Leetcode 11: Container with Most Water

Tags: solution-verification, algorithms

I understand that there is a post about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435662/proof-more-rigorous-for-leetcode-11-container-with-most-water-problem) but I was wondering if there was a way to make my proof work.

Statement of the problem:

> You are given an integer array height of length n. There are n
> vertical lines drawn such that the two endpoints of the ith line are
> (i, 0) and (i, height[i]). Find two lines that together with the
> x-axis form a container, such that the container contains the most
> water. Return the maximum amount of water a container can store.
> Notice that you may not slant the container.

My solution:

```
class Solution:
def maxArea(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
    leftptr = 0
    rightptr = len(height)-1
    area = 0
    
    while(leftptr<rightptr):
        area = max(area,min(height[rightptr],height[leftptr])*(rightptr-leftptr))
        if(height[leftptr]>height[rightptr]):
            rightptr-=1
        else:
            leftptr+=1
    
    return area
```

Now, for my proof, since this is a greedy problem, I thought I would show that at each step, we have the max area. So in my proof, I claim that we find the max area for width $k$ for $k \in [1,n-1]$, and thus, find the maximum area. I proceed by induction.

The base case is easy, since there is only one rectangle of width $n-1$, and I thought this might be the right way to approach it since going from here, to width $n-2$, there are only two rectangles to consider, and we increment/decrement to the correct one.

My induction hypothesis is that for width greater than $k$, we have the rectangle of the greatest area. Thus, I need to prove that the rectangle of width $k-1$ needs to lie completely inside this rectangle of width $k$. I could not do this, and I actually found a counterexample.

Consider the following heights array: $[10,7,10,1,10,1]$. It correctly finds the maximum area(between indices $0$ and $4$) but since the $0$th and $4$th indices have the same height, it actually never finds the greatest area rectangle of width $1$(mine outputs 1, but it should be 7). Is my method of proof not going to work? Is there a way to make it work?

It just seems weird to me that this greedy algorithm is correct even though we don't consider the maximum area rectangle for every single width in the algorithm.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A sketch for a proof that your algorithm really finds the largest area:

1. There will be an integer pair $(r,s)$ with $0\le r < s \le n-1$ such that the container formed by the $x$-axis and the $r$-th and $s$-th line has the maximum area (as defined for the problem). There might be many different pairs, but we only need one.
2. Your algorithm ends, and it does with leftptr=rightptr. In each loop step exactly one of leftptr and rightptr changes by excatly 1, so both go through all integers from their starting to the ending value.
3. Your final leftptr=rightptr will be $\ge r$ or $\le s$ (or both).
4. If $r=0$ and $s=n-1$, then you found the max area already in the first step.
5. Since your leftptr started at $0$ and rightptr at $n-1$, that means leftptr was $r$ at some point before the loop ended, or rightptr was $s$ before the loop ended (maybe both)
6. Let's go to the step of the algorithm where this first happened. Since only one of leftptr, rightptr changes after each step, we have leftptr$=r$, rightptr $> s$ or leftptr $< r$, rightptr$=s$. The only exception is if it happens in the first step already, but that is covered in 4).
7. Both situations from 6 are work out the same way, so we consider here only leftptr$=r$, rightptr $> s$.
8. If, at the above step, we had height[leftptr] $\le$ height [rightptr], then the pair (leftptr, rightptr) would form a better container (higher area) than $(r,s)$. That's because it has a longer base, and the water height it can contain is heihgt[leftptr], while the water height the $(r,s)$ container can contain is **at most** heihgt[leftptr] (=heihgt[r]).
9. That means we actually have height[leftptr] $>$ height [rightptr]. That means in that step, rightptr gets decremented, and so it continues until finally rightptr=s, which means that you will "find" that maximum container with your algorithm.